# A question about conditional construction

Tags: conditional-constructions

My  question is about the type of conditional verb  in the past(condition and condition's result is about the past).

A: I don’t understand this.

B: If I were you, I would ask your teacher for help.

---

A: I didn't understand this yesterday.

B: ?

How can I Answer the B ? Can I say "If I were you, I would have asked your teacher for help."

Comment: I'm closing this question for the moment because asking to "find the mistakes" is off-topic here. I'm guessing you want to know if the phrase, "If I were you, ..." is still correct when talking about actions in the past. That's a great question, but it must state that clearly in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is OK but has ideas that are implied:

A: I didn't understand this yesterday, but I understand it now.

B: If I were you, I would have asked your teacher for help rather than spending many hours in the library.

("spending" might be changed to "wasting", also "in the library" might be changed to other research methods.)

Comment: Thank you  for the answer       .